# Is there any etymological link between Monopoly and Politic?

Tags: etymology

In economic circles, the idea is occasionally floated that the etymology of Monopoly, is something along the lines of:

```
Mono - One
Pol  - Political
Y    - Entity
```

Working under the idea that the only way monopolies emerge is if an entity is given a legal privilege. For example, tariffs on imports on widgets, grants the local widget producer a monopoly.

This makes sense to me, however when checking https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=monopoly -- Pol is referred to  `pōlein "to sell," from PIE root *pel- (4) "to sell."` and makes no reference to politics

Etymonline is not always the most reliable source, and there could be ideological pressure to not associate Monopoly with the State. Thus I am asking for a second opinion.

Is there any etymological link between Monopoly and Politic?

Answer (score 1):

The English word is not a coinage. Per the OED, it is a borrowing from the Latin *monopōlium*, which in turn was taken from the Greek *μονοπώλιον*; cognates exist in the various Romance languages.

> μονο- mono- comb. form
>    + πωλεῖν to sell (see *-pole* comb. form)
>    + -ιον , suffix forming nouns (compare *-y* suffix).

There are at least several Greek words which contribute to *pol* in English words, mostly via Latin and French.

- There is πολύς, meaning *many*, which gives rise to *poly-* in words like *polyester*, *polytheism*, or *polyamory*.
- There is πωλέω, to sell or trade, whence the non-productive and increasingly obscure *-pole* in words like *pharmacopole*, *bibliopole*, and *monopole* (a *monopoly* is a right held by a *monopole*).
- There is πόλις, meaning a Hellenic city-state, found in words like *politics*, *metropole*, and *megalopolis*.

The suggested alternative etymology makes no sense. A mono+polis+y would be the state or condition of being a single city. Sure, politics is involved in the awarding of monopolies, but to some extent, politics is involved with everything. As to "ideological pressure" on Etymonline… really?

Comment: `Hellenic city-state` != `a single city` ; Ancient Athens and Sparta were effectively countries. Thus, `A mono+polis+y would be the state or condition of being a single country.` is more accurate.